# How to ignore special characters in string

Tags: ruby, string, special-characters

I know that in C#, we can use operator for strings when we need to use special characters as letters inside of it. It's like `%"!@#*&#Y!@#*&!@#\123"`. Does anyone know how we can do that on Ruby?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Ruby, you can use `'` or `"` as your string delimiter. The former doesn't do any special character handling within the string, not even things like `\n`; the latter does.